# Bash: how to check if directory exists?

Tags: bash, shell

I have written following `if-else statement` to check if `directory1` or `directory2` exists or not

```
if [ -d /opt/directory1 ] || [ -d /opt/directory2 ]; then
 echo "SUCCESS"
else
 echo "FAil
fi
```

However, on some servers I am getting an error

```
[: /opt/directory1: binary operator expected
```

All servers are using `bash`

Comment: how can I check the shell version?

Comment: @rkta has a point. Are you sure that all your servers are using Bash (as suggested by the tags)? Maybe some of them are running another shell: tcsh, ksh, zsh... You can check which shell you're currently running with the command `echo $0`.

Comment: all servers are using `bash` I have checked it as well

Comment: (Aside from a missing dbl-quote in your code), https://shellcheck.net didn't actually say, you need a `-d`, but it did point to the correct place that caused your problem. So please check your code there before posting here. Glad you got it sorted (weird that some servers allowed it and some complained., compare with `echo $BASH_VERSION`). Good luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Bash, this will give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
if [[ -d /opt/directory1 ]] || [[ -d /opt/directory2 ]] ; then
    echo "SUCCESS"
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
```

Note the usage of `-d` on both conditions.

Comment: I am getting `FAIL` as output even when the `directory` is existing. Do you think it might be related to permission given to the directory?

Comment: @meallhour Permissions to the directory itself doesn't matter, but you need at least search ("execute") permission to its parent directory and each directory on the path to it. So for `[[ -d /foo/bar/baz ]]`, you need access to /foo and /foo/bar, but not /foo/bar/baz.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Shell script give you an answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$1"

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 {dir-name}"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -d "$DIR" ]
then
    echo "$DIR directory  exists!"
else
    echo "$DIR directory not found!"
fi
```